# Allow transparently altering View's underlying table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

How to create a view that does not prevent altering its underlying table? There's a certain reason why I can't drop and re-create the view every time I need to change a column type or add a new column. This is because the alter script is generated by our ORM when we change the complex type definition and there's a stable deployment procedure I don't want to change.

```
-- test initialization
drop view if exists test_dep_trk_v;
drop table if exists test_dep_trk;
create table test_dep_trk ( a varchar(10) );

-- the view MUST at all times contain all the columns of the table
create view test_dep_trk_v as select * from test_dep_trk;

-- this statement cannot be changed
alter table test_dep_trk alter column a type varchar(11);
```

.

```
ERROR:  cannot alter type of a column used by a view or rule
DETAIL:  rule _RETURN on view test_dep_trk_v depends on column "a"
SQL state: 0A000
```

Comment: What is the reason?

Comment: I'm not sure you are following the way Postgres is working. If you are changing the column type you are also invalidating all structures required by the view to function. Recreating the view manually might look like wasting your time, but actually, it makes you think more about your database structure before changing it. And if you have a good reason to not drop a view, might that be also a reason to not alter the underlying table? Actually, I think, with proper use of transactions you can make view recreation totally invisible to other consumers.

Comment: It's not like I don't want to drop the view. I just want to make this transparent to the ORM. Updated the question

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of obfuscation layers. Unfortunately there is no workaround to this (admittedly annoying) limitation - this is how Postgres works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this can be done with the event triggers of 9.4. There are some weak points:

- `pg_trigger_depth()` always returns zero (Is this a bug?). This is why I had to use a non-temporary table to prevent recursion.
- We need to filter by the altered object name, but there's no way to get it in 9.4. `current_query()` returns the client's statement even if we're called from a stored procedure.

_

```
create UNLOGGED table IF NOT EXISTS test_dep_trk_trig_data ( pid integer primary key );

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_dep_trk_trig() RETURNS event_trigger AS $$
DECLARE
    v_query text;
BEGIN
  if NOT exists( select * from test_dep_trk_trig_data where pid = pg_backend_pid() ) then
    insert into test_dep_trk_trig_data ( pid ) values ( pg_backend_pid() );
    v_query := lower( current_query() );
    if (v_query like '%test_dep_trk%' and not v_query like '%test_dep_trk_v%') then
      -- RAISE NOTICE '%', v_query;
      drop view if exists test_dep_trk_v;
    end if;
    delete from test_dep_trk_trig_data where pid = pg_backend_pid();
  end if;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN
    delete from test_dep_trk_trig_data where pid = pg_backend_pid();
    RAISE;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;



CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_dep_trk_trig_end() RETURNS event_trigger AS $$
DECLARE
    v_query text;
BEGIN
  if NOT exists( select * from test_dep_trk_trig_data where pid = pg_backend_pid() ) then
    insert into test_dep_trk_trig_data ( pid ) values ( pg_backend_pid() );
    v_query := lower( current_query() );
    if (v_query like '%test_dep_trk%' and not v_query like '%test_dep_trk_v%') then
      -- RAISE NOTICE '%', v_query;
      create view test_dep_trk_v as select * from test_dep_trk;
    end if;
    delete from test_dep_trk_trig_data where pid = pg_backend_pid();
  end if;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN
    delete from test_dep_trk_trig_data where pid = pg_backend_pid();
    RAISE;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER test_dep_trk_trig ON ddl_command_start EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_dep_trk_trig();
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER test_dep_trk_trig_end ON ddl_command_end EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_dep_trk_trig_end();
```